# create new recipient with docusign using apex toolkit

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I am using the Docusign apex toolkit to send a document to be signed. the problem that I want to declare a new recipient (it is not stored in salesforce DB) so I have tried to use the function

`dfsle.Recipient.newRecipient`

but I have got this error

> `Method is not visible: dfsle.Recipient
>   dfsle.Recipient.newRecipient(Integer, String, dfsle.Recipient.Role,
>   String, String, dfsle.Recipient.Authentication, String, Boolean)`.

also, i have tried to use the function

```
dfsle.Recipient myRecipient1 = dfsle.Recipient.Recipient(id, type, sequence, routingOrder, role, name, email, signingGroup, phone, authentication, note, emailSettings, hostName, hostEmail, signNow, source, readOnly, required)` but I have got this error: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Recipient(Id, String, Integer, Integer, NULL, String, String, NULL, String, NULL, String, NULL, String, String, Boolean, NULL, Boolean, Boolean)
```

from the type **dfsle.Recipient** .

noting that I am not using the method

`dfsle.Recipient.fromSource`

because i want to create new recipient without an object stored in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly add recipients using name and email address directly in apex:

In the example mentioned on our Developer site
https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/code-examples/salesforce-sending-signing-template

Example for our site
//use the Recipient.fromSource method to create the Recipient

```
dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
myContact.Name, // Recipient name
myContact.Email, // Recipient email
null, //Optional phone number
'Signer 1', //Role Name. Specify the exact role name from template
new dfsle.Entity(myContact.Id)); //source object for the Recipient
```

Updating this example for adding recipients outside Salesforce

```
dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
Name, // External Recipient name
Email, // External Recipient email
null, //Optional phone number
'Signer 1', //Role Name. Specify the exact role name from template
null); //add source object here as null
```